# divergence or convergence .

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let  $u_{n},v_{n}$ be real series such that $$\begin{cases} u_{0}=\alpha \\ v_{0}=\beta \\ 0 < \alpha < \beta \end{cases}$$ and $$\begin{cases} u_{n+1}=\dfrac {u_{n}^{2}} {u_{n}+v_{n}}\\ v_{n+1}=\dfrac {v_{n}^{2}} {u_{n}+v_n }\end{cases}$$
Put $x_{n}=\dfrac {u_{n}} {v_{n}} ,y_{n}=u_{n}-v_{n} $. I need to know the limit of $x_{n},y_{n},u_{n},v_{n}$
if it do not diverge .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that:
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{u_{n+1}}{v_{n+1}}=\frac{u_n^2}{v_n^2}=x_n^2=x_{n-1}^4=\cdots=x_0^{2^{n+1}}=\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)^{2^{n+1}}$$
So, since $\alpha<\beta$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)^{2^{n}}=0$$
On the other hand,
$$y_{n+1}=u_{n+1}-v_{n+1}=\frac{u_n^2-v_n^2}{u_n+v_n}=\frac{(u_n-v_n)(u_n+v_n)}{u_n+v_n}=u_n-v_n=y_n=y_0=\alpha-\beta$$
so the sequence is constant and the limit is:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=\alpha-\beta$$

Now, **if all limits exist** (this remains to be proved), we have:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}v_n \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}v_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n -\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=-\alpha+\beta$$